# Always upgrade to latest stable release of every library , good or bad practice?

Tags: programming-practices

So we are writing medium size software,and it has two parts frontend is written in angularJS and backend in laravel. Laravel provides api and nothing else. 
Now very often one of many dependencies gets updated. 
Now shall we take the bite and upgrade or do not disturb the system since it is working fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping tech support on the latest software version](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/186906/keeping-tech-support-on-the-latest-software-version)

Comment: @gnat: I don't see how.

Comment: Have you considered how long it would take to test these upgrades?

Comment: @JeffO- See backend is almost fully tested, unfortunately I can't say the same for AngularJS frontend. So honestly I am not much worried about backend. But to answer your question no, we do think that most of them are patches, rather than api breaking upgrades so no more than 15 minutes of backend unit testing and around 2-3 hours of e2e manual testing.

Comment: This question should probably note that its for web development, since answers may differ for application development where users download and run the software locally, and you do regular builds which are tested before a stable release.

Comment: @ideasman42-No that is not case at all.

Answer (score 5):

Bad practice generally, unless you want to be on the bleeding edge and have to manage bugs you can't control.

However, a policy of continuous upgrading is a good practice, you manage the pain of upgrading if you do it regularly as changes should not be that large. One day you will have to upgrade (eg to fix a security vulnerability) and if you're many versions behind the upgrade could be a major undertaking.

So really its a management exercise in trading off upgrades against maintenance churn. Do it regularly, but not simply because a new version has been released.

Comment: @gbjbaanb- I am not getting you, why bad. We are updating only stable (though latest) releases. I am just trying to juggle which one would be better in long term that is shall we burn out small issues due to upgrade or may suffer major crash in long term due to not up gradation.

Comment: You still need to thoroughly test the new version. Even stable updates may introduce bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I would *generally* recommend keeping up to date.

If you don't, at some stage you will have to upgrade your library (have you found a bug?), and that may cascade through your project and your dependencies, as the new library requires further updates.

If you *schedule* regular minor upgrades, then you can manage that without having an avalanche of upgrades when your hand is forced. Note that I'm suggesting that you schedule this - perhaps you timebox it, and if an upgrade requires more work, at least you can back off and allocate more time to it. I am (of course) assuming you have a regression test set such that you can determine that your functionality remains the same!